# Proof that trace is non-negative: positive definite matrix and a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and $b$ be some vector.  Then show
\begin{align}
\textrm{Tr}(A^{-1}bb^T A{-1})\geq 0
\end{align}
I'm not sure how to show this.  Any tips?  It's from p. 13 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02845.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTS: $tr(A^{-1}bb^TA^{-1})$ (as stated in the paper)

First $A$ positive definite implies $A^{-1}$ positive definite. Define $y = b^TA^{-1}$. Then using the commonly assumed fact that positive definite implies symmetric, we have

$$
tr(A^{-1}bb^TA^{-1}) = tr(y^Ty) \geq 0
$$

where the inequality follows because $y^Ty = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$.